# Assert call to method using Mock python

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to do some unit testing using the mock library in Python. I have the following code:

```
def a():
    print 'a'

def b():
    print 'b'
    if some condition
        a()
```

How do I assert that a call for `b` has been made when a mock call to `b` has been made? I have tried the following code, but it failed:

```
mymock=Mock()
mymock.b()
assertTrue(a.__call__ in mymock.mock_calls)
```

For some reason, I think that the `mymock.b()` has nothing to do with the method `b()`. What can be done for this?

Answer (score 7):

If you patch `a`, you can ensure it was called like so:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.a') as fake_a:
    b()
    fake_a.assert_called_with()
```

If your method is in a different module:

```
import mymodule

with mock.patch('mymodule.a') as fake_a:
    mymodule.b()
    fake_a.assert_called_with()
```

Comment: i am getting AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: Are you using the mock module or making a Mock()? For this you simply need `import mock`

Comment: Don't make a Mock object, just import mock

Comment: Sionide, i managed to accomplish the test by using mock. now i have a question regarding one of the methods. if the method a has been imported, then how to accomplish the patch?

Comment: Sionide, I tried that. i have an import like this:

    from xyz import abc

I tried this:

    with mock.patch('xyz.abc.a') as fake

Answer (score 3):

> Somehow, I think that the mymock.b() has nothing to do with the method b() What can be done for this?

You're right. When you mock an object, you're implying that you don't care about what your mock does behind the scenes. If you wanted to make sure that `a` was called from `b`, you would want to [patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html) `a` in `b`.

```
>>> from mock import patch
>>> with patch('__main__.a') as patch_a:
...     b()
...     patch_a.assert_called_with()
```

So, the moral of the story is, mock or patch over the object that you want to measure without actually calling, not the object whose implementation you care about. In this case you care about `b` and want to find out how it uses `a`. Since we don't care what `a` does, only that it is being called, we can patch over it.

Additionally, if you want more detail about the calls to a, instead of `assert_called_with` you can analyze all of the calls made by accessing the patches `mock_calls` attribute. In this case it would be `patch_a.mock_calls`.

Comment: I've used this code with what you've posted above (the only difference being I replaced `some condition` with `True:`). It ran without error. If you're getting an error, please **edit your question** and post the actual code that is giving you trouble and a stack trace. Without that information I can't do anything to help you troubleshoot.